# COUNT and GROUP BY several columns

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I got table like this where I want to calculate "WeekCount" so that number of "Done" is counted but grouped by Cycle and a Week.
|

| ID | Day | Cycle | Week | Done |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 8 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 9 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT a.ID, COUNT (a.Done) as Count_Done,a.Cycle,a.Week 
FROM #Table a
JOIN #Table b ON a.ID=b.ID AND a.Cycle=b.Cycle AND a.Week=b.Week
WHERE a.Done=1
GROUP BY a.ID,a.Cycle,a.Week
```

but I am getting count of all rows , not just those where "Done=1"
like this:

| ID | Count_Done | Cycle | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 | 1 |

while I am expecting result like this:

| ID | Count_Done | Cycle | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you need to join the table a second time at all.

I suspect the following will give you what you want. Since it's not joining the table a second time, the only rows it will see are the ones with `Done=1` so the counts will be correct:

```
SELECT a.ID, COUNT (a.Done) as Count_Done,a.Cycle,a.Week 
FROM #Table a
WHERE a.Done=1
GROUP BY a.ID,a.Cycle,a.Week
```

If you want to include id/cycle/week combinations that have the count as 0, I suggest using `SUM` instead of `COUNT` (if your done values are truly 0/1):

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.Done) as Count_Done,a.Cycle,a.Week 
FROM #Table a
GROUP BY a.ID,a.Cycle,a.Week
```

Or maybe

```
SELECT a.ID, COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Done=1 THEN 1 END) as Count_Done,a.Cycle,a.Week 
FROM #Table a
GROUP BY a.ID,a.Cycle,a.Week
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was basically joining with the same table cause my bigger problem was to update specific column in the same table with these values, so left that approach, but I can easily break those steps and use simple GROUP BY as you suggested.  Thanks again.